# What is the "type" of an ES6 class getter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, getter

I have a class that looks like this:

```js
export class WidgetsManager {
  private foo?: boolean;
  private bar?: boolean;
  // ... and so on

  constructor(config: Config | null) {
    this.foo = config.foo;
    this.bar = config.bar;
    // ... and so on
  }

  get hasFoo(): boolean {
    return this.foo === true;
  }

  get hasBar(): boolean {
    return this.bar === true;
  }

 // ... and so on
}
```

And I create an instance like this:

```js
const mgr = new WidgetsManager({
  foo: true, bar: true,
  // ...and so on, each attribute === true
});
```

I want to write a unit test and avoid having to write out each and every getter (it's a long list) that I want to test. So I use the following:

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(mgr).forEach(attr => expect(truthyMgr[attr]).toBeTruthy())
```

The code above give a TS error saying

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WidgetManager'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'WidgetManager'.ts(7053)
```

What is the correct type to use for `attr` in this situation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with whether the property is a getter or not. The problem simply is that `attr` has type `string` not `keyof WidgetsManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a quirk of the typing for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Basically the reason why the type of the parameter is `Record<string, any>` is because you can't maintain any other type invariant. An object can match an interface but have more properties defined on it.

See [this github issue on the typescript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15570) for more info.

Comment: Right so the workaround would be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(mgr).forEach(attr => expect(truthyMgr[attr as keyof WidgetsManager]).toBeTruthy())` then?

Comment: That should be correct yes